# SharePoint Workflow -External mail id

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I want to send mail to the user having xxx@gmail.com using workflow 2013.

I have full access to the sharepoint 2013
I don't want to use code.
Is it possible to achieve this .

Answer (score 2):

You can't send external emails using SharePoint 2013 designer workflow template. But You can achieve this using SharePoint 2010 workflow template.

1. Select **"SharePoint 2010 Workflow"** As Platform Type while creating workflow in designer.

[image]

2. Use **Send Email** Action to send emails.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply Vishal . I already choose Sp2010 platform and use this email option but in this i can send mail to the user having company mail id .
I want to send mail to their personal mail id like gmail or yahoo .
How can i achieve this is their any other way

Comment: Store users personal email in one of the user profile properties then get that property in workflow send email action & send emails to their personal email ids.